# An expression to represent all possible arrangments of a set of length n into 3 (infintely sized) bins?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I have a set, A = {1,2}

And I generate a set, B, of all possible arrangements of the above set across 3 "bins" (note where 1 and 2 are together, they are summed):

```
{{{},{1},{2}},
{{},{2},{1}},
{{},{1,2},{}},
{{},{},{1,2}},
{{1},{2},{}},
{{1},{},{2}},
{{2},{1},{}},
{{2},{},{1}},
{{1,2},{},{}}}
```

**Is there a concise algebraic expression for B, in terms of A?**

I am trying to find this for the general case where A has length n.

The first step, I think, is to find the power set of A:

$\mathcal P(A)$ = {{},{1},{2},{1,2}}

The next step is to find all combinations across three "bins", ensuring that no duplication occurs (aside from the empty set). But I am struggling to work out to concisely present this.

**EDIT:**

I have come up with the following, using powersets. However, I am sure it can be made more concise:

$$B = (x,y,z) \forall x\in \mathcal P(A) \\
\forall y \in \mathcal P(A) if |x \cap y|<1 \\
\forall z \in \mathcal P(A) if |x \cap y \cap z| <1$$

**EDIT 2:**

Thanks to the answer and comments for @String and @ErickWong below, I have come up with another representation:

$$
a \in\begin{cases}
x&\text{ if }d_i=0\\
y&\text{ if }d_i=1\\
z&\text{ if }d_i=2
\end{cases}  \forall a, i \in A,\{0,1,...,n-1\} \forall d \in D_{3,n}
$$

Where $D_{3,n}$ is a set of the n-digit ternary numbers,

This should work regardless of what the actual values in A are, which is an advantage. I still wonder if this could be improved, however. I will post any improvement I come up with here.

Comment: Doesn't it correspond to $n$-digit ternary numbers?

Comment: @string thanks. Whilst there are some similarities, I don't think it does exactly correspond.

Comment: @atomh33ls What part of the correspondence is missing?  Your example looks exactly like it corresponds to the nine $2$-digit ternary numbers $12,21,11,22,01,02,10,20,00$.

Comment: @ErickWong Probably down to my inexperience in this area, but, looking at [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ternary.html), I couldn't see how the duplicate empty sets would be included e.g. `{1,2},{},{}}`.

Comment: @atomh33ls The $n$th digit corresponds to which bin contains the value $n$.  Thus each empty set is represented by not containing a particular digit.  The strings $00,11,22$ correspond to `{{1,2},{},{}}, {{},{1,2},{}}, {{},{},{1,2}}`.

Comment: @ErickWong, Well put. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In the comment section, you suggested that it does not exactly correspond to $n$-digit ternary numbers. I think it does, but maybe I misinterpreted your question. Here is what I think, then we can discuss it:

---

Write ternary digits $d_1,d_2,...,d_n$. Then form the three sets $S_1,S_2,S_3$ as follows:
$$
i\in\begin{cases}
S_1&\text{ if }d_i=0\\
S_2&\text{ if }d_i=1\\
S_3&\text{ if }d_i=2
\end{cases}
$$
Then each $i\in\{1,2,...,n\}$ is assigned to one of the three sets $S_1,S_2$ or $S_3$. Each constellation where $i$ belongs to a different set is in $1-1$ correspondence with a different $n$-digit ternary number. There will be $3^n$ of them.

Comment: yes perhaps I wrong to dismiss it. I would expect $3^n$ output sets as you suggest. However I couldn't see how the duplicate empty sets would be introduced, e.g. `{{1,2},{},{}}`

Comment: @atomh33ls: That corresponds to $d_1=d_2=0$ or put differently, the ternary number $00$. Then both $i=1$ and $i=2$ go to $S_1$, and $S_2=S_3=\emptyset$.

Comment: Ahh... beginning to sink in! Thanks.